# Migrating to a DataGrid using UiBinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

There is already a Grid to display some information in a tabular form, in a project that uses UiBinder to bind the components. I want to migrate this to use a DataGrid instead, except that I'm unable to find a good tutorial on how to do so - the few sites talking of this assume that its done programmatically which is not what I'm looking for.

My actual issue *right now* is that I can't even get DataGrid to show the emptyTableWidget (a simple HTML label with 'No data' text). However, I would prefer an answer or link to info with detailed steps on how to go about using a DataGrid, including:

- changes needed in the UiBinder template
- Translating custom cells like checkboxes to use Column models instead
- adding the old column 'headers' to the DataGrid, so they can be fixed (on scrolling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGrid requires that the application is using RootLayoutPanel instead of RootPanel, which I had overlooked.

I switched to using CellTable instead, as we are adding multiple widgets to RootPanel etc. - basically updating the initialization and layout to move to RootLayoutPanel wouldn't be a minor task, and doesn't justify doing it just to avoid scrolling/pagination via CellTable ;)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Datagrid showcase sample](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid).
It contains a `DataGrid` defined with UiBinder and custom columns.

The reason why the `DataGrid` is probably not showing anything is that you have to put into a `LayoutPanel` or any other `Panel` that implements the `ProvidesResize` interface.

Comment: I do have it in a `LayoutPanel`, and also the UI does 'reserve' a block of space for the datagrid - I see 200px height in my tab just empty. Problem is, it should show a label 'No Data' (thru `setEmptyTableWidget`) which is not the case.